# AppSettings in Config file cannot be more than one

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I want to have some reference from another config file to the master config file (web.config), but I am always get this error when there is two ***`<appSettings file="ReferenceURL">`*** in web.config.

For example:

**web.config**

```
< configuration >
< configSections />
< appSettings file="Forgot.config">
< appSettings file="Login.config">
< /configuration>
```

**Forgot.config**

```
< appSettings >
< add key="Name" value="Value">
< add key="Name" value="Value">
</appSettings >
```

**Login.config**

```
< appSettings >
< add key="Name" value"Value">
< appSettings >
```

Whenever I want to try to run the program, I always got this error:

```
Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic < location > for exceptions.
```

The reason why I got 2 different config file, but in the above example got same `< appSettings >`, is because one of them is only being used for ***"Forgot Password Page"***, and the rest of it is only being used for ***"Login Page"*** and also to keep the ***"web.config"*** tidy and clean and easy to read.

Is there any way that I can accomplish this?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @JHLAI it would be tidy and clean when you use same config with and From that you can reference it to your aspx page